# Handling fairly large amounts of data over multiple fragments to read and write from a Sqlite DB in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments

Looking for some advice on the best way to go about this as I'm new to this.

I have an `android` app that is basically a huge form split over around 30 `fragments`. I have approximately 800 `fields` split over these `fragments` that I need to output to a `database`.

I need to store these forms on the device so they can open up previous ones and these will of course then populate from the database and when saved will update the db. I've decided to go down the Sqlite route rather than the content provider.

I have two `activities`, my `main` which is a list of `forms` on the device and the second is the `edit form activity` which uses a `ViewPager` to navigate the `fragments`.

So my question is, how am I best going about getting the data to save/update from the `fragments`? I know I need to use an `interface` and I was thinking that each `fragment` will need an `interface` to pass the values from the `editText` fields (using `getText` and `findViewbyID`) through to the edit form `activity` which will have the method for the the save button which will then pass through all the variables to the `Update` query sitting on the `dbHelper` class.

Does this seem the right way to do things or does anyone have a better suggestion? Seems like this will be quite messy.

Thanks,

Comment: Why will this be messy?

Comment: Just thought it would be due to the amount of variables and passing them through the interface and then into the query. Thought there might be a simpler way where the variables can all be set/controlled at one level but seems like they all have to be set at Fragment level when each view is inflated and then passed over bit by bit.

Comment: Cann't you update query at fragment?

Comment: Yes I could, but as I need the entire form to update at once (not sure what the write times will be on this) so the user doesn't have to click save on every fragment, I think the principal will be the same in that I will still need to accumulate all date from all fragments at the save method. I might be missing something here so feel free to correct me!

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own implementation of `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` or `ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener`, this will allow you to save content directly after page was turned to the next.

[OnPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html)

[SimpleOnPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener.html)

Comment: That's very useful, thanks. I will definitely implement that!